# Selecting the most recent, lowest price from multiple vendors for an inventory item

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group, distinct-on

I’m fairly proficient at SQL, however this question has had myself stumped for quite a while now. In the most basic sense, there are simply two tables:

```
Items
+----+--------+
| id | title  |
+----+--------+
|  1 | socks  |
|  2 | banana |
|  3 | watch  |
|  4 | box    |
|  5 | shoe   |
+----+--------+
```

...and the prices table:

```
Prices
+---------+-----------+-------+------------+
| item_id | vendor_id | price | created_at |
+---------+-----------+-------+------------+
|       1 |         1 | 5.99  | Today      |
|       1 |         2 | 4.99  | Today      |
|       2 |         1 | 6.99  | Today      |
|       2 |         2 | 6.99  | Today      |
|       1 |         1 | 3.99  | Yesterday  |
|       1 |         1 | 4.99  | Yesterday  |
|       2 |         1 | 6.99  | Yesterday  |
|       2 |         2 | 6.99  | Yesterday  |
+---------+-----------+-------+------------+
```

(Please note: created_at is actually a timestamp, the words “Today” and “Yesterday” were provided merely to quickly convey the concept).

My goal is to get a simple result back containing the inventory item associated with the most recent, lowest price, including the reference to the vendor_id who is providing said price.

However, I find the stumbling block appears to be the sheer number of requirements for the statement (or statements) to handle:

- Each item has multiple vendors, so we need to determine which price between all the vendors for each item is the lowest
- New prices for the items get appended regularly, therefore we only want to consider the most recent price for each item for each vendor
- We want to roll all that up into a single result, one item per row which includes the item, price and vendor

It seems simple, but I’ve found this problem to be uncanningly difficult.

As a note, I’m using Postgres, so all the fanciness it provides is available for use (ie: window functions).

Comment: What do you mean "most recent lowest price"?  Do you want the lowest price?  Or the most recent?  Or some combination of the two?

Comment: @GordonLinoff: Additional explanation further down clarifies that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Much simpler with `DISTINCT ON` in Postgres:

#### Current price per item for each vendor

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (p.item_id, p.vendor_id)
       i.title, p.price, p.vendor_id
FROM   prices p
JOIN   items  i ON i.id = p.item_id
ORDER  BY p.item_id, p.vendor_id, p.created_at DESC;
```

#### Optimal vendor for each item

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (item_id) 
       i.title, p.price, p.vendor_id -- add more columns as you need
FROM (
   SELECT DISTINCT ON (item_id, vendor_id)
          item_id, price, vendor_id -- add more columns as you need
   FROM   prices p
   ORDER  BY item_id, vendor_id, created_at DESC
   ) p
JOIN   items i ON i.id = p.item_id
ORDER  BY item_id, price;
```

[->SQLfiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!12/a57ff/8)

Detailed explanation:
[Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)

Comment: This shows each vendor's current price. I believe the OP also wants to know the optimal vendor for each item. That can be done by turning the answer into a subquery and then doing `SELECT DISTINCT ON(item_id) * FROM the_subquery ORDER BY price`, yes?

Comment: OMG SQLFiddle is a thing! Anyhow, Andrew is right, I wouldn't want multiple results of socks, only a single result for each item.

Comment: @AndrewLazarus: Right, the second step was missing. Added that. `ORDER BY` needs to match `DISTINCT ON`, though. So we need `ORDER  BY item_id, price`.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter: Even Homer nods.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
CREATE TABLE #Prices ( Iid INT, Vid INT, Price Money, Created DateTime)
INSERT INTO #Prices 
SELECT 1, 1, 5.99 ,GETDATE()    UNION
SELECT 1, 2, 4.99 ,GETDATE()    UNION
SELECT 2, 1, 6.99 ,GETDATE()    UNION
SELECT 2, 2, 6.99 ,GETDATE()    UNION
SELECT 1, 1, 3.99 ,GETDATE()-1  UNION
SELECT 1, 2, 4.99 ,GETDATE()-1  UNION
SELECT 2, 1, 6.99 ,GETDATE()-1  UNION
SELECT 2, 2, 6.99 ,GETDATE()-1 

WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT 
        MyPriority = ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( partition by Iid, Vid ORDER BY Created DESC, Price ASC) 
    ,   Iid
    ,   Vid
    ,   price
    ,   Created
    FROM #Prices 
)

SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE MyPriority = 1
```

Comment: Very close - however, this results in an item_id being returned for each vendor_id. What would be the best way to get that down to a single item_id?

Answer (score 0):

It's also possible to do this with windowed functions, it will work on SQL Server version > 2005:

```
with cte1 as (
    select
        *,
        row_number() over(partition by vendor_id, item_id order by created_at desc) as row_num
    from prices
), cte2 as (
    select
        *,
        row_number() over(partition by item_id order by price asc) as row_num2
    from cte1
    where row_num = 1
)
select i.title, c.price, c.vendor_id
from cte2 as c
    inner join items as i on i.id = c.item_id
where c.row_num2 = 1;
```

[**<kbd>sql fiddle demo</kbd>**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!12/a57ff/21)(Thanks Erwin)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the below query would work using a windows function and being quicker then using distinct.

```
select rank() over (partition by p.item_id order by created_at desc, price) as rank, p.item_id,p.vendor_id,p.price,I.title
from prices as p
inner join Items as I
on I.ID = P.Item_ID
where rank = 1
```